# javascript split on non-alphanumeric an keep delemiters at start

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm currently recoding some of my PHP code into javascript code for my node.js server.

My PHP-Reqex looks like this:

```
$timevalue = "W5D4H7M34S12";
$aSplitted = preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', $timevalue);
```

The result for $aSplitted looks like this:

```
["W5","D4","H7","M34","S12"]
```

This is what I tried in javascript:

```
var aSplitted = timevalue.split(/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i/g);
```

Or

```
var aSplitted = timevalue.split((?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i);
```

Or

```
var aSplitted = timevalue.split('(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i');
```

but it wont work.

I've also tried something like this:

```
var aSplitted = timevalue.split(/[^A-Za-z]/);
```

But it only gives me the chars without the numbers after.

Maybe some of you know the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `split` accepts the delimiter, and splits the string by the delimiter. You are looking for `match`.
2. In the JavaScript syntax, `#` should be replaced with `/`. But you've combined the PHP and JS syntax, not valid.
3. Lookbehinds are not supported by JS
4. Just simplify it.

To get the matches, you should use

```js
var timevalue = "W5D4H7M34S12";
var aSplitted = timevalue.match(/[a-z]\d+/ig);

document.write(JSON.stringify(aSplitted))
```

Comment: Did you run it? Invalid regex

Comment: Oh, and there's another problem also. Deleting while fixing.

Comment: @Code fixed. You've made a typo also, it's not `stringyfiy`, but `stringify` :)