# Insert multiple text single textarea in node js forEach

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, foreach, handlebars.js

How am I working with nodejs, mysql, forEach trying to save the email in my BD with a unique id, using the textarea tag, based on this question

[Insert multiple email to mysql using single textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199912/insert-multiple-email-to-mysql-using-single-textarea)

[For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

[javascript split on non-alphanumeric an keep delemiters at start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435371/javascript-split-on-non-alphanumeric-an-keep-delemiters-at-start)

```
<form class="" action="/registration/instudent/{{id_school}}/{{mat}}/{{grade}}" method="post">

<textarea name="email" ></textarea>            
<button class="btn btn-lg">Save</button>

</form>
```

Using the example in PHP base, in my file example.js I have this code, try to save only the email value of my textarea tag.

```
router.post('/instudent/:id_school/:mat/:grade', isLoggedIn, async (req,res) => {
const { id_school, mat, grade } = req.params;
const { email } = req.body;

const e = email.match('\r\n');

//var e = ["a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com", "c@gmail.com"];

//const uStudent = {
//    id_school,
//   mat,
//   grade,
//    email
//  };

e.forEach(function(email, indice, array) {

//     await db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', [uStudent]);

db.query("INSERT INTO date (email) VALUES (email)");
console.log('this is my email:',email);
});
//res.redirect('/');
});
```

If I try to save all the variables by executing the loop asynchronously, I find the following error.

```
const uStudent = {
id_school,
mat,
grade,
email
};
await db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', [uStudent]);

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: uStudent.forEach is not a function
```

If I insert two emails this way.

```
db.query("INSERT INTO date (email) VALUES (email)");
```

In my database I only see the blank fields, someone can help me or give me a guide to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', uStudent)`?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same, I throw the following error:                        (node:39926) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: uStudent.forEach is not a function

Comment: If this is the [`mysql` driver on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), then you appear to be doing it correctly. Are you sure it's emitted by that line? Personally I prefer to use [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/), but the approach is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help, it's correct you told me [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) correctly inserted in this way to my database.

```
db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', uStudent)
```

The correct way I managed to insert data is to help me in this question

[Why is “forEach not a function” for this object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096596/why-is-foreach-not-a-function-for-this-object)

Then my code would look like this, I hope it helps, since I've been trying to save in database with forEach for several days.

```
router.post('/instudent/:id_school/:mat/:grade', isLoggedIn, async (req,res) => {
  const { id_school, mat, grade } = req.params;
  const { email } = req.body;

  var uStudent = {
    id_school,
    mat,
    grade
}

Object.keys(uStudent).forEach(function (key){
    console.log(uStudent[key]);
    db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', uStudent);
});
  //res.redirect('/');
});
```